# $.post with serialize doesn't send post variables and values

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to post data with jquery to process.php, and return everything what happens in the process.php file.

I already managed to load the file with ajax. if I type

```
echo "Hello world!";
```

it does return Hello world! but it does not return the echoes where I use $_POST.

The form

```
<form class="calc" method="POST" action="process.php">
<input id="calc-average" type="text" name="calc-average" placeholder="Goal"/>
<input id="calc-weight" type="text" name="calc-weight" placeholder="Weight"/>
<input id="calc-calculate" type="hidden" name="calc-calculate" value="1" />
<input type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary calc-submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

The script

```
 $(".calc").submit(function(event) {  
            event.preventDefault();   
            $.post( 'process.php', $(".calc").serialize(),  
              function( data ) {  
                  $(".result").append(data);  
              }
            );
});
```

Process.php

```
if(isset($_POST["calc-calculate"])&&isset($_POST["calc-weight"])&&isset($_POST["calc-average"])){
    if(!$_POST["calc-calculate"]==""&&!$_POST["calc-weight"]==""&&!$_POST["calc-average"]==""){
        if($_POST["calc-calculate"]==$subjectid){
            $a = $_POST["calc-weight"];
            $y = $_POST["calc-average"];
            $q = $weights;
            $z = $average;
            $tobe = (-($a*$y+$q*$y-$q*$z)/$a)*-1;
            if($tobe>10 or $tobe<0){
                echo " | Not possible yet";
            }else{
                echo " | The grade you need is: " . round($tobe,1);
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "Hello wordl!";
```

If I remove the if statements it returns that they are unidentified.

So does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: check console for errors

Comment: That's true. But it could be that the serialize is not working I thought...

Comment: @TusharGupta XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:8080/grades/process.php".  Nothing is wrong there.

Comment: At the start of your process.php, try to add : `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: @CronosS Thanks! Now I get: Array ( [calc-average] => [calc-weight] => [calc-calculate] => 5 ). So I know calc-average and calc-weight aren't posted. What to do?

Comment: Do you have multiple forms in your html page ? If so, you should try `$.post( 'process.php', $(this).serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

hi can you please try this in your jquery code

```
$(".calc").submit(function(event) {  
            event.preventDefault();   
            $.post( 'process.php', $(".calc :input").serialize(),  
              function( data ) {  
                  $(".result").append(data);  
              }
            );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me.

try adding `return false` after `post` request.

```
$(".calc").submit(function(event) {  
        event.preventDefault();   
        $.post( 'process.php', $(".calc").serialize(),  
          function( data ) {  
              $(".result").append(data);  
          }
        );
      return false;
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. Thanks to CronosS I know it's because of multiple forms with same class. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

I already had the same problem. My code had a duplicate "id" on the page. That was my issue.
Please, make sure you have an exclusive id or class "calc" in the form to "serialize" command call the correct element.